# Conditional handler based on slug in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to react. I am using React Route and I would like to know if it's possible to execute a different handlers based on a slug passed to the route.

For example I have the following route:

```
<Route name="page" path={'/:slug'} />
```

Is it possible to dynamically set the handler to be executed based on that slug?

I couldn't find anything on their API/Examples.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that React/JSX gives you the full power of JavaScript. That means your route handler component can do whatever it wants--including rendering children conditionally. Something like this may work (I haven't run this, so consider it pseudocode):

<sup>Note: I'm using the 0.13 syntax since that appears to be the version you're using.</sup>

```
var slugsToHandlers = {
  'about': AboutPage,
  'jobs': JobsPage,
};

var SlugRouteComponent = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.func
  },

  render: function() {
    var slug = this.context.router.getCurrentParams().slug;
    var Handler = slugsToHandlers[slug] || NotFundPage;
    return <Handler {...this.props} />;
  }
});

// ...

<Route name="page" path="/:slug" handler={SlugRouteComponent} />
```

You could also, if you wanted, list each route individually:

```
<Route name="aboutPage" path="/about" handler={AboutPage} />
<Route name="jobsPage" path="/jobs" handler={JobsPage} />
<Route name="page" path="/:slug" handler={NotFoundPage} />
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see a working demo of this solution! I would expect react/ JSX to always look for a `<Handler/>` component. Did not know (haven't tried yet) that you could assign components dynamically this way (depending on slug render either an `<ÀboutPage/>` component or a `<JobsPage/>` component, especially with the props part.

Comment: @wintvelt Remember that JSX components are just JavaScript objects! When you type `<About>`, JSX converts this into `React.createElement(About)`. So, `About` can be a reference to any component! I'll work on a demo later.