# Render Child Component based on route param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I have a react router implemented as such:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={IndexPage} />
      <Route name="listView" path="things" component={ThingsList}>
        <Route name="expandedView" path=":_id" component={ThingExpanded} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById("body"));
```

I'm rendering the list, and registering the route with no problem. with below component.

```
let ThingsList = React.createClass({
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {things.map((thing) => {
          return (
            <li key={things._id}>
              <Link to={`/things/${thing._id}`}>
                <span>{thing.firstName}</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
          )
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
})
```

But how can I show additional data, when one clicks the link and registers the route for expanded view of a particular item? I need to read the router info, and accordingly render the additional info. I mean it should not be based on onClick, based on the route. Something like this?:

```
componentDidMount () {
  let rName = Router.getName;

  if (rName == "expandedView") {
     let rSlug = Router.name("expandedView").slug("_id");
     this.setState({expand: true, which: rSlug});
  }
}

render() {
  let extra;
  if (this.state.expand) {
    extra = <ThingExpanded />
  }
}
```

and then in the List component:

```
render() {
  return (
    ...
    <Link to={`/things/${thing._id}`}>
      <span>{thing.name}</span>
      {extra}
    </Link>
  ...)
}
```

Note: This answer is very close to what I need, but didn't work. :/
[Conditional handler based on slug in React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889075/conditional-handler-based-on-slug-in-react-router)

Comment: which version of React Router are you using? I recommend upgrading to the 1.0 final. Named routes are gone in 1.0

Comment: oops, actually it's v1.0. The name I gave just as reference. But how would you fix it?

Comment: I would use the `location` which is on the `context`

Comment: You mean like: this.context.location? It logs undefined on the console.

Comment: you need to specify it first: `YourComponent.contextTypes = { location: React.PropTypes.object }`

Comment: Hmm. Now I receive the location object. Thanks! How can I get the param? I receive the **hash** field but its value is the full path. I need to get the id.

Comment: sorry I thought you want to grab the `pathname`, the `params` can be found in the `props`: `this.props.params.id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94722/discussion-between-emo-and-knowbody).